# Objective c/c++ : error when assign NSArray value into c++ static array

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

When I assign NSArray value into C++ static array, it will give me "No viable overloaded '='" error. Here are my codes :

At the beginning, I declare

```
    static std::string usbInfors[ARRAY_ROW]; // save usb infor
```

Then, I included String header, and change my file to .mm

```
    NSMutableArray *saveElement = [NSMutableArray new];
    int countOfUSB = 0; //count of usb drive

    .... //collected data and put into saveElement array

    NSArray *arrayOfUSBInfor = [NSArray arrayWithArray:saveElement];
    [saveElement dealloc];
    countOfUSB = [arrayOfUSBInfor count];
    for(int i=0; i< countOfUSB; i++){
        usbInfors[i] = [arrayOfUSBInfor objectAtIndex:i];//This line gives me error
    }
```

Thanks !!

Comment: You need to brush up on your C, your C++ *and* your Objective-C, there are a lot of issues here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well assuming that `arrayOfUSBInfor` is an array of `NSString` objects, you'll need:

```
for(int i=0; i< countOfUSB; i++){
    usbInfors[i] = [[arrayOfUSBInfor objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String];
    //                                                ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

in order to assign `const char *` to `std::string` rather than `NSString *`.

Also this looks suspect:

```
[saveElement dealloc];
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
[saveElement release];
```